# At what point to use unique_lock with shared_mutex?

Tags: c++, c++17

Typically, when using a "normal" mutex, you would use it as in `remove1()`.
However, now with `shared_lock` and `unique_lock`, should you use a shared lock first and the unique lock only when necessary? Note that `remove()` may not need to `unique_lock` when the model does not exist.

```
void remove1(int id) {
    std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutex_);
    for (auto it = models_.begin(); it != models_.end(); ++it)
        if ((*it)->getId() == id)
        {
            it = models_.erase(it);
            return;
        {
}

void remove2(int id) {
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> sharedLock(mutex_);
    for (auto it = models_.begin(); it != models_.end(); ++it)
        if ((*it)->getId() == id)
        {
            sharedLock.unlock();
            std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(mutex_);
            models_.erase(it);
            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: I think remove1() is correct. I have some suspicions about what would happen if remove2() is called concurrently in different threads (imagine trying to erase the same object.)

Comment: Considering that `shared_lock` and `unique_lock` have completely different semantics, why would you use `shared_lock` when you're locking for exclusive access? Equally important, neither of those types came out with C++17; are you thinking about `scoped_lock` which did ship with C++17?

Comment: offtopic: both version of `remove` are buggy. `remove1`: if there are two consecutive items to remove second one will be skipped. `remove2` operates on invalid iterator after one remove.

Comment: Also OT: A) `remove1()` will actually invoke UB if the last element is removed because `++it` happens after the loop body execution but before the check. (Put the `++it` in an `else` instead.) B) `remove1()` does not need to use `std::unique_lock`; `std::lock_guard` (actually `std::scoped_lock` in C++17 code, thanks Nicol Bolas) is sufficient here.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think the implication is that there are other threads which only read from the list and use `std::shared_lock`.

Comment: @Marek, the data structure will only hold one unique copy for each ID, therefore the implementation of remove() is correct. insert(id) will ensure there is no instance of a given ID before inserting.

Comment: @aCuria implementation suggest something else since when item is found search is continued.

Comment: @Marek, I fixed the implementation in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> sharedLock.unlock();
> std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(mutex_);
> ```

Just because two operations are individually atomic does not mean that one followed by the other represents an atomic sequence. Once you give up a lock, you *give it up*. If that mutex guards access to the container, there's nothing preventing the iterator you have from being invalidated.

What you're trying to do is have the inner `unique_lock` atomically upgrade the outer `shared_lock` in exclusive mode. That can't be done in C++17 at all.

And of course, you never re-lock the `shared_lock` before you leave the `if` block, so after erasing one element, you're in trouble.

And that ignores the fact that whenever you `erase` an element from either of your loops, you'll skip the next one. The iterator returned by `erase` points to the next element, and your `++it` in the loop header will skip it. This is true of both functions.

But in any case, the overall purpose of `shared_mutex` is to permit multiple readers but only one modifier. Your entire operation is really a modification operation. It may be conditionally modifying, but atomically it is a modification operation. What you want is for everyone to either see the list as it was before the operation or for everyone to see the list as it was *after* all matching elements are erased. Nobody should ever see the list while you're modifying it.

So it should use exclusive access.

Comment: [`boost::upgrade_mutex`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.upgrade_mutex) could be used instead of `std::shared_mutex` if there is only 1 thread that needs to modify the data structure (e.g. producer). For multiple producers, even this is difficult to use because there is – even conceptually – no way to satisfy two concurrent lock upgrade attempts – either attempt will have to fail. `remove2` could then release the shared lock and fall back to a (fixed) version of `remove1`, but the overall cost will be higher.